# Ошибка doInBackground()

Tags: java, android

Проблема с doInBackground() и курсором:

[image: Приложение запускается и через секунду вылетает]

115-135 строки файла `ftuesday.java`:

```
    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {

    DB db;

    public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DB db) {
        super(context);
        this.db = db;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {
        Cursor cursor = db.getAllData();
        try {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(0);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       return cursor;
    }

}
```

Метод getAllData() в классе DB.java:

```
    public Cursor getAllData() {
    return mDB.query(DB_TABLE, null, null ,null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

В чём может быть проблема? Или одну и ту же таблицу нельзя выводить в разных окнах?

Comment: Объект  ```mDB``` равен ```null```. Почему он ```null``` знаете только вы.

Comment: А он может обнулиться как-то? потому что я его использую в нескольких классах, работает нормально, а именно во фрагменте `ftuesday` возвращает `null`. Может перегрузка этой многопоточности и всякого непонятного?

Comment: Сам по себе нет, если только вы передали туда null, либо где то в этом классе принудительно обнулили его сами. Запустите приложение в debug режиме и смотрите что туда приходит.

Comment: Как инстанцируется mDB?

Comment: Многопоточное же приложение. Может в потоке не существует инстанса для mDB.

Comment: Эврика! Спасибо) нашёл кусок, у меня на `onStart` событие почему-то не работало, я перенёс функцию открытия доступа к базе в `onCreate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В логе написано, что `mDB == null`.

Возможны 2 варианта :

1. Скорее всего дело в том, что вы инициализиуете mDB на одном экране, а используете на другом (или не экране, а сервисе). 
   Это частая ошибка - не учитывать очистку контекста (со всеми переменными).
2. База просто не инициализировалась на телефоне - поэтому `mDB=null`. А в логе может не быть сообщений потому что он обернут в `try/catch`.